# Is it possible to have more than 4 valuebox in a single row with flexdashboard?

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, r-plotly, flexdashboard

I want to have 6 valuebox in a single row, but it seems that 4 is the maximum. When I try to do 6, the valuebox wouldn't fit. I wonder if this is possible in flexdashboard? Thanks in advance! [image: Picture for 4 valuebox]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any trouble rendering many value boxes, you didn't provide a reproducible question, and you asked a while ago. So to address your question, I'm going to provide the code I used to make many value boxes in the same `flexdashboard`.

I'm going to assume that you have a good working knowledge of how it comes together since you made the dashboard pictured. However, if you do find this answer and something doesn't make sense, don't hesitate to ask me questions.

````
---
title: "SOQ ValueBoxes Et cetera"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
    vertical_layout: scroll
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
```

Row {data-height=100}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### this box

```{r v1}

valueBox("111", icon = "ion-ionic", color="#007dbc")
```

### this box

```{r v2}

valueBox("111", icon = "ion-ionic", color="#007dbc")
```

### this box

```{r v3}

valueBox("111", icon = "ion-ionic", color="#007dbc")
```

### this box

```{r v4}

valueBox("111", icon = "ion-ionic", color="#007dbc")
```

### this box

```{r v5}

valueBox("111", icon = "ion-ionic", color="#007dbc")
```

### this box

```{r v6}

valueBox("111", icon = "ion-ionic", color="#007dbc")
```

Row {data-height=250}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}
head(mtcars)
message(summary(cars))
```

Row {data-height=100}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### More boxes
```{r}
# Manual number reached
valueBox("111", icon = "ion-ionic", color="#007dbc")
```

### Again and again
```{r}
# Manual number reached
valueBox("111", icon = "ion-ionic", color="#007dbc")
```

Row {data-height=450}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart B

```{r}

p1 = plot_ly( # random plot
    data = mtcars,
    x = ~mpg,
    y = ~cyl)
p2 = plot_ly(
    data = mtcars,
    x = ~disp,
    y = ~drat)
```

<div style="display:flex;flex-direction:row;">
<div style="display: flex; max-width: 50%;">

`r p1`

</div><div style="display: flex; max-width: 50%;">

`r p2`

</div></div>

### Random Latin
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
````

[image]